# Adding Maven archetype in Intellij failing (does not exist)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-archetype, archetypes

This is driving me nuts. I created a spring boot project using Maven a week ago and when I went to create another today the archetype was not listed. I tried using the "Add Archetype" option, but when I enter the info I get an error telling me that the archetype doesn't exist:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-
plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired 
archetype does not exist (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-
parent:1.3.3.RELEASE) -> [Help 1]
```

To be clear I entered this information when adding the archetype:

```
GroupID: org.springframework.boot
ArtifactId: spring-boot-starter-parent
Version: 1.3.3.RELEASE
```

Found here: [Link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.3.3.RELEASE)
This also leaves a broken archetype the library now too.

Additionally, I tried creating an empty project and generating the archetype using the command:

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find 'spring-boot-starter-parent' so I used 'spring-boot-blank-archetype' instead. It executes successfully, but nothing happens in IntelliJ; it remains completely blank. However, if I access the file through the file system on my computer I see that the a correct file structure exists: pom, iml, demo app and all.

I tried rebuilding the project in Intellij I receive this error:

```
Error:Failed to load project configuration: cannot read file /path/to
/directory/.idea/modules.xml: 
/path/to/directory/.idea/modules.xml:  (No such file or directory)
```

Not sure what this means and couldn't find anything useful online.

My questions:

1. How do I add an archetype in maven correctly? (or what am I missing?)
2. What does that error mean and can it be fixed?

Extras:

- Running Ubuntu
- Running IntelliJ 15.0.4
- Running JDK 8
- Favorite color is yellow (but more on the golden side)